# Titanium with REST API

Tags: php, rest, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am trying to call a REST API developed in PHP. My Titanium Code is pretty simple.

```
var url = "http://www.sample.com";
    var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient(
    {
        // function called when the response data is available
        onload : function(e) 
        {
            Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
            alert('success');
        }
    });
    // Prepare the connection.
    client.open('GET', url,true);
    // Send the request.
    client.send();
```

I get the error as below

```
[INFO] :   Received text: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
[ERROR] :  was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
[INFO] :   <html><head>
[INFO] :   <title>403 Forbidden</title>
[INFO] :   </head><body>
[INFO] :   <h1>Forbidden</h1>
[INFO] :   <p>You don't have permission to access /
[INFO] :   on this server.</p>
[INFO] :   <p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
[ERROR] :  <hr>
[ERROR] :  <address>Apache Server at www.sample.com Port 80</address>
[ERROR] :  </body></html>
```

I thought that this has to do with the parameter Access-Control-Allow-Origin, i changed that parameter to *, but it was of no use.
I was able to call the API from the normal HTML + JS code after changing the ACAO parameter.
Please help.
Thanks and Regards Abhishek

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the url you are calling is correct?

Comment: Yes, because it seems to work on the browser.